# Text file combining script - Python - Big Data

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, text

I was wondering if anyone could help me come up with a better way of doing this,

basically I have text files that are formatted like this (some have more columns some have less, each column separated by spaces)

```
AA BB CC DD Col1 Col2 Col3
XX XX XX Total 1234 1234 1234
Aaaa OO0 LAHB TEXT 111 41 99
Aaaa OO0 BLAH XETT 112 35 176 
Aaaa OO0 BALH TXET 131 52 133
Aaaa OO0 HALB EXTT 144 32 193
```

These text files ranged in size from a few hundred KB to around 100MB for the newest and largest filesWhat I need to do is combine two or more files by adding the checking to see if there are any duplicate data first of all so checking if AA BB CC and DD from each row match with any rows from the other files, if so then I append the data from Col1 Col2 Col3 (etc) on to that row, if not then I fill the new columns in with zeros. The I calculate the top 100 rows based on the total of each row and output the top 100 results to a webpage.

here is the python code I'm using

```
import operator

def combine(dataFolder, getName, sort):
    files = getName.split(",")
    longestHeader = 0
    longestHeaderFile =[]
    dataHeaders = []
    dataHeaderCode = []
    fileNumber = 1
    combinedFile = {}
    for fileName in files:
        lines = []
        file = dataFolder+"/tableFile/"+fileName+".txt"
        with open(file) as f:
            x = 0
            for line in f:
                lines.append(line.upper().split())
                if x == 1:
                    break
        splitLine = lines[1].index("TOTAL")+1
        dataHeaders.extend(lines[0][splitLine:])
        headerNumber = 1
        for name in lines[0][splitLine:]:
            dataHeaderCode.append(str(fileNumber)+"_"+str(headerNumber))
            headerNumber += 1

        if splitLine > longestHeader:
            longestHeader = splitLine
            longestHeaderFile = lines[0][:splitLine]
        fileNumber += 1

    for fileName in files:
        lines = []
        file = dataFolder+"/tableFile/"+fileName+".txt"
        with open(file) as f:
            for line in f:
                lines.append(line.upper().split())
        splitLine = lines[1].index("TOTAL")+1
        headers = lines[0][:splitLine]
        data = lines[0][splitLine:]
        for x in range(2, len(lines)):
            normalizedLine = {}
            lineName = ""
            total = 0
            for header in longestHeaderFile:
                try:
                    if header == "EE" or header == "DD":
                        index = splitLine-1
                    else:
                        index = headers.index(header)
                    normalizedLine[header] = lines[x][index]
                except ValueError:
                    normalizedLine[header] = "XX"
                lineName += normalizedLine[header]
            combinedFile[lineName] = normalizedLine
            for header in dataHeaders:
                headIndex = dataHeaders.index(header)
                name = dataHeaderCode[headIndex]
                try:
                    index = splitLine+data.index(header)
                    value = int(lines[x][index])
                except ValueError:
                    value = 0
                except IndexError:
                    value = 0

                try:
                    value = combinedFile[lineName][header]
                    combinedFile[lineName][name] = int(value)
                except KeyError:
                    combinedFile[lineName][name] = int(value)

                total += int(value)
            combinedFile[lineName]["TOTAL"] = total
    combined = sorted(combinedFile.values(), key=operator.itemgetter(sort), reverse=True)
    return combined
```

I'm pretty new to Python so this may not be the most "Pythonic" way of doing it, anyway this works but its slow (about 12 seconds for two files about 6MB each) and when we uploaded the code to our AWS server we found that we would get a 500 error from the server saying headers were too large (when we tried to combine larger files). Can anyone help me refine this into something a bit quicker and more suited for a web environment. Also just to clarify I don't have access to the AWS server or the setting of it, that goes through our Lead Developer, so I have no actual clue on how its set up, I do most of my dev work through localhost then commit to Github.

Comment: If your code runs without any errors, [codereview.se] might be a better place to ask.

Comment: It runs without issue on my machine, but when we put it live online we get an error 500 from the server saying the headers are too large (Only when we combine larger files, small files are fine)
-edit: Also didn't know Code Review even existed, I'll post this on there as well